# Как понять на какой странице произошло зацикливание

Tags: php, linux, рекурсия, symfony

Сайт `mysite.ru` написан на Symfony 1.4. При открытии не удается понять, на какой именно странице зависает сайт. Стек: `Linux+Nginx+Apache`

Если бы я сумел понять, на какой странице происходит зацикливание, то пофиксил бы. Страниц очень много. Есть ли способ на уровне PHP или может на уровне сервера отловить эту страницу?

Comment: лог смотрите, там по таймилимиту отпадывать должно с 500й ошибкой, скорее всего. в логе должна быть URL запроса

Comment: @teran Запрос начинается и не заканчивается ,если бы он закончился с 500 ошибкой то да.

Comment: стандартный лимит времени выполнения скрипта не более 3 минут кажется, если у вас висит бесконечно, то сходите в [настройки пхп](http://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) и верните его. Если лимит времени включен, то удостоверьтесь, что у вас там редиректов по кругу нет никаких (в инструментах браузера)

Comment: @teran max_execution_time = 30 Он и так у меня такой

Comment: `set_time_limit` поищите по коду

Comment: @teran И допустим нашел.В самом `core`  symfony1.4.Сразу скажу это не дело находит их и удалять.Нужно независимо не от чего остановить долгоиграющий скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - проверь наследования в (Twig) Шаблонах.
У меня происходило зацикливание когда я наследовал (Twig)Шаблон который в котором происходило наследование дочернего =)